# How can I update password or other attributes in below XML using c#

Tags: c#, xml

How can I update password or other attributes in connection string in XML using c# .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="abcConnection" connectionString="server=10.10.12.12;database=Test1;uid=myUI‌​D;password=hello;tim‌​eout=20;"providerNam‌​e="System.Data.SqlCl‌​ient" />
        <add name="123Connection" connectionString="server=10.10.23.45;database=test2;uid=MyUS‌​I;password=hello;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

it can be any xml file not the config from the same application .
Please help.

Comment: this is my XML please help.

Comment: Please post your xml in the question because it a lot cleaner.
And you should write what you already tried.

Comment: If you want generic xml reader then you've to make a parser by yourself.

Comment: Without any attempted code to start with, this question is a duplicate of any older "how to parse XML using C#" kinda questions...

Comment: I was able to update the attributes using XMLDocument but connection string attribute itself contains other attributes which I am not able to .

Comment: @RaghvendraYadav Then this question has nothing to do with XML. XML model recognize attribute value as a unit, i.e a string in your case. Once you managed to get the `connectionString` value, you need to do string manipulation operation to get/update specific part of the string i.e password

Comment: Thanks har07 .It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

You can Update your xml anyway:

use this reference:

```
 using System.IO;
```

use this code:

```
   var XMLpath = "c:\test.xml"; //<< your xml here
    if (!File.Exists(XMLpath))
    {
        using (StreamWriter XmlWrite = new StreamWriter(XMLpath, false))
        {
            string[] x = {@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>",
                           @"<configuration>",
                           @"<connectionStrings>",
                           @"<add name=""abcConnection"" connectionString=""server=10.10.12.12;database=Test1;uid=myUI‌​D;password=hello;tim‌​eout=20;""providerNam‌​e=""System.Data.SqlCl‌​ient"" />""",
                           @"<add name=""123Connection"" connectionString=""server=10.10.23.45;database=test2;uid=MyUS‌​I;password=hello;"" providerName=""System.Data.SqlClient"" />",
                           @"</connectionStrings>",
                           @"</configuration>}";
            foreach (string s in x)
            {
                XmlWrite.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
```